# Type safety through inheritance (2)

Tags: c#

This is an extension to my previous question: [Type safety through inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186267/type-safety-through-inheritance)

I created a new question instead of updating my old as this one dives deeper into this topic.

My original purpose was to declare a method that returns an object of the implementing classes type. One such method might look like `GetSimpleClone()` in the following:

I have a base interface `IEntity` that declares the method `GetSimpleClone()` and is implemented by several other interfaces, for example `IPerson`.

```
public interface IEntity<T> : where T : IEntity<T>
{
   T GetSimpleClone();
}

public interface IPerson : IEntity<IPerson>
{
}
```

The interface `IAddress` also implements `IEntity`. However another interface `IVenue` inherits from `IAddress`. As I described in the beginning, I want the `GetSimpleClone()` method in `IAddress` to return an object of type `IAddress` while the same method in `IVenue` should return an object of type `IVenue`. Therefore the declaration of `IAddress` differs from `IPerson` as it has to declare a generic type itself:

```
public interface IAddress<T> : IEntity<T> where T : IAddress<T>
{   
}

public interface IVenue : IAddress<IVenue>
{
}
```

Now the problem is that `IPerson`has a reference to `IAddress` and understandably the compiler forces me to define the generic type of `IAddress`.

```
public interface IPerson : IEntity<IPerson>
{
   IAddress<"Compiler: Define Type!!"> Address { get; set; }
}
```

I really can't see a solution to this problem and would appreciate any help from you, even if it is just to say that there is simply no solution. :)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `public interface IEntity<T> : where T : IEntity<T>` what is the point of this?

Comment: This ensures two things: The method GetSimpleClone() can only return types of IEntity and the type of T is equal to the interface that inherits from IEntity.

Comment: @Thomas: But the constraint does *not* ensure those things. The constraint ensures that `T` is an `IEntity<T>`, which is not an equality constraint.

Comment: To clarify my last comment: If you have `class Cat : IEntity<Cat>` then you can also have `class Dog : IEntity<Cat>` -- the constraint does not enforce the rule that the class must construct the interface with itself at all.

Comment: That's true, but when i declare the interface ICat as `interface ICat : IEntity<ICat>` and let my `class Cat` implement from it, than the method `GetSimpleClone()` will return objects of type `ICat`. This is quite a specific example but the main question is: How can I declare a method in a base interface and ensure that its return type is equal to the interface that inherits the base interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish that, you will need to introduce yet another generic:

```
public interface IPerson<T> : IEntity<IPerson<T>>
    where T : IAddress<T>
{
   IAddress<T> Address { get; set; }
}
```

The better solution I could think of is just to put aside the safety thing and create a good base `IAddress` interface with a common methods, like `getAddressString`, and use it for all types of addresses you may want to have.

Comment: This works until you implement the Interface IPerson. At this point you have to specify the concrete type of T. I usually use interface types on references as well and this would not be possible with your approach. However as this is probably the only solution I'll mark your post as answer.